# Xslt move tag to new element one level up

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml,

And i need to move the Line tag out from the Hader tag

and into new Lines tag

```
<Msg>
  <Header>
    <a>Header Text</a>
    <Line>
        <Lid>1</Lid>
        <Ltext>abc</Ltext>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Lid>2</Lid>
        <Ltext>def</Ltext>
    </Line>
  </Header>
</Msg>
```

**transform it to:**

```
<Msg>
  <Header>
    <a>Header Text</a>
  </Header>

  <Lines>
    <Line>
        <Lid>1</Lid>
        <Ltext>abc</Ltext>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Lid>2</Lid>
        <Ltext>def</Ltext>
    </Line>
  </Lines>
</Msg>
```

How can i do this using XSLT?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways this could be done. Here's one:

**XSLT 2.0+**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Header">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="* except Line"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <Lines>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Line"/>
    </Lines>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MEdvhd

**XSLT 1**

Replace

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="* except Line"/>
```

With

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(local-name()='Line')]"/>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MEdvhd/1

**To change Line element name to Detail, add another template:**

```
<xsl:template match="Line">
  <Detail>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Detail>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks thats work
What if i need to change the name of the <Line> tag to <Detail> how i can do it?

Comment: @yadv See the last part of my updated answer.